# SparkSQL Column Query not showing column contents?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

I have created a persistant table via `df.saveAsTable`

When I run the following query I receive these results

```
spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM mytable """).show()
```

I get view of the DataFrame and all of it's columns, and all of the data.

However when I run

```
spark.sql("""SELECT 'NameDisplay' FROM mytable """).show()
```

I receive results that look like this

```
|  NameDisplay|
|--|
| NameDisplay | 
| NameDisplay | 
| NameDisplay | 
| NameDisplay | 
| NameDisplay | 
| NameDisplay |
```

NameDisplay is definitely one of the columns in the table as it's shown when I run `select *` - how come this is not shown in the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was using quotes on the column names. Needs to be escaped via backtick ``NameDisplay`

Answer (score 0):

Selecting `'NameDisplay'`, in SQL, is selecting the literal, text "NameDisplay". In that, the result you got are in fact valid.

To select values of the "NameDisplay" column, then you must issue:

```
"SELECT NameDisplay FROM mytable "
```

Or, if you need to quote it (maybe in case the column was created like this or has spaces, or is case-sensitive):

```
"""SELECT `NameDisplay` FROM mytable"""
```

This is SQL syntax, nothing specific to Spark.

Comment: Thank you! However I found that the double quotes did not work either, I needed to escape via back-tick `